# Can Any One Solve a Display Error On Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

When i wrote a program on assembly language more specifically .asm file
on compiling it and executing it on tasm compiler we got a error on display
Instead of Numbers we are getting corresponding asci codes

i had Checked on the web,
and refereed with the friends

i am currently using a Tasm Compiler

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
num db 5,4,7,0,1,9,3,6,8,2
msg db 'NUMBERS in sorted order:$';
.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov ah,00h
mov al,ah
qq:
mov cl,09h
mov si,00h
yy:
mov al,num[si]
inc si
cmp al,num[si]
jc xx
mov bh,num[si]
mov num [si],al
dec si
mov num[si],bh
inc si
xx:
dec cl
jnz yy
dec bl
jnz qq
lea dx,msg
mov ah,09h
int 21h
lea dx,num
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end
```

output was [image]

Comment: You need to include more details about what exactly the output was vs. what exactly the *desired* output was.  i.e. what the program is supposed to do.  This isn't a [mcve].  It's also an unreadable wall of code with no indenting, comments, or blank lines between blocks, even after I fixed the Stack Overflow code formatting.

Comment: But anyway, obviously you have an array of integers, not ASCII codes for digits.  It's not a string.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why won't the program print the sum of the array?](//stackoverflow.com/a/53252729) - you need an `add reg, '0'` in there somewhere

Comment: you answered your own question.  it is printing ascii characters. so if you want to see '1', '2', etc then you need to send the ascii character for '1', '2', '3'.  Look at an ascii chart.

Comment: A quick workaround: Change `num db 5,4,7,0,1,9,3,6,8,2` to `num db "5470193682$"` (**with** quotation marks and dollar sign). You can sort single-digit numbers as ASCII letters as well.

Comment: Why am I the only one wondering about the error message claiming the file isn't even there?

Answer (score 2):

```
num db 5,4,7,0,1,9,3,6,8,2
```

What you defined here is that in the address that num is pointing to you used a byte for 5, then a byte for 4, a byte for 7, etc.

```
msg db 'NUMBERS in sorted order:$';
```

Here you made a string, a string is for making our life easier, what you did here is in the address that msg is pointing to you defined a byte for 78 (N is 78 in ASCII), byte for 85, etc.

So you have 2 solutions here,
or you are changing the numbers to string

```
num db "5 4 7 0 1 9 3 6 8 2"
```

or you are going to add 48 in decimal to every number (48 - 0 in ASCII, 49 - 1, 50 - 2 etc)

```
mov si, offset num
mov cx, 10
numberToASCII:
    add byte ptr [si], 48
    inc si
loop numberToASCII
```

consider that this program is for 10 numbers in the num variable, and it only works for numbers from 0 - 9

Comment: `"5 4 7 0 1 9 3 6 8 2"` with ASCII spaces between each value is an array twice as long; the current sorting code wants to sort contiguous bytes, not bytes at even addresses separated by spaces.  And it still doesn't have a `$` terminator that `int 21h`/`ah=9` needs.  See [@rkhb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57653186/can-any-one-solve-a-display-error-on-assembly-language#comment101764643_57653186).  You have the right idea but that's *not* a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Also, `[ax]` isn't a valid addressing mode.  Only `bx|bp  + si|di` (or a subset of that with only 1 register instead of 2) are valid.  And you would need `add byte ptr [di], 48` because neither operand implies an operand size.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for the response, but I have to clarify, the thing is that he wanted to print the numbers, this is just more formated way to print then to print all the numbers together, I didn't use the `$` terminator because he can print the numbers and the text would print automatically (as I am writing this I realized it should be the opposite first text and then numbers, as for the second comment, you are 100% right.

Comment: Right, it would be *most* efficient to put the buffer right after the constant string so the two form one big string.  Then the `$` terminator has to go after the end of `num`.  Or your answer could suggest printing 1 digit at a time in a loop instead of creating a string in memory (so you don't need literal spaces).  Anyway, the OP's code still has a hard-coded length of 9 contiguous bytes.  If you run that on a string of 9 ASCII digits + 8 spaces (`0x20`), you won't get the desired result.  So you need to either mention using offsets of 2 bytes when sorting or drop the spaces from that idea.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right, I just didn't think about this too much, I will fix it when I will be back on the computer.

Answer (score 2):

#### I'm puzzled

As [z0rberg's commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57653186/can-any-one-solve-a-display-error-on-assembly-language#comment101821986_57653186) the screenshot tells us that TASM couldn't find your source file. This will imply that the subsequent use of the linker TLINK will have acted upon an old version of the object file, one that does not include the latest modifications to the program source. Why do you even run the application in this case?

#### Why it doesn't work at all

> ```
> lea dx,num
> mov ah,09h
> int 21h
> ```

This DOS output function expects that `DX` points at a "$" terminated text. Your code does not provide this. The "$" is missing and the bytes at the address *num* are not the characters "0" through "9" that you might think.

As [Erik Gelfat explained in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57653186/can-any-one-solve-a-display-error-on-assembly-language/57660332#57660332) `num db 5,4,7,0,1,9,3,6,8,2` places the bytes 5, 4, 7, ... in memory where the above used DOS function would work fine if these bytes were 53, 52, 55, ... (which normal people will write as "5", "4", "7", ...)

My solution is to not use function 09h but rather write a loop that uses function 02h. This way you can easily convert the number into its textual form by adding 48.

```
 mov cx, 10
 lea si, num
More:
 mov dl, [si]
 inc si
 add dl, 48
 mov ah, 02h
 int 21h
 dec cx
 jnz More
```

#### Why it doesn't work well

> ```
> dec bl
> jnz qq
> ```

Your program nowhere initializes this `BL` register! Depending on whatever value there happens to be in `BL`, your code will do too few iterations to get the numbers sorted or your code could be doing hundreds of iterations too many. Luckily these redundant iterations will not destroy the end result, but still...

The program implements a Bubble-sort algorithm. The idea of Bubble sorting is that the biggest element will *bubble* to the top (the rear of the array). This immediately means that at the completion of the inner loop you need no longer look at this biggest element because it is at its final place. **You can reduce the task by 1 element each time the inner loop finishes**. Your code does not do this since you always set `CL=9`.

This is your code with the correct use of `BL`:

```
 mov BL, 9
qq:
 mov cl, BL
 mov si,00h
yy:
 mov al,num[si]
 inc si
 cmp al,num[si]
 jc xx
 mov bh,num[si]
 mov num [si],al
 dec si
 mov num[si],bh
 inc si
xx:
 dec cl
 jnz yy
 dec bl
 jnz qq
```

#### Writing it somewhat better

- Giving labels descriptive names (my choice, other people will make other choices)
- Preferring `JB` over `JC` because Jump If **Below** better expresses what happens here
- Using the addressing modes that are available. You can address the byte before `SI` if you write `mov num[si-1], al`
- Clearing a register is usually done by XORing it with itself. Instead of `mov si, 0`, you can write `xor si, si`
- Adding a few explaining comments

Draft 1:

```
 mov dx, 9         ;This is number of elements minus 1
OuterLoop:
 mov cx, dx        ;This is what actually reduces the task
 xor si, si
InnerLoop:
 mov al, num[si]   ;Reading 2 successive array elements
 mov bl, num[si+1]
 cmp al, bl        ;Comparing as UNsigned numbers
 jb  NoSwap
 mov num[si], bl   ;Writing them in reverse order
 mov num[si+1], al
NoSwap:
 inc si
 dec cx
 jnz InnerLoop
 dec dx
 jnz OuterLoop
```

Draft 2 (loosing most of the displacements):

```
 mov dx, 9         ;This is number of elements minus 1
OuterLoop:
 mov cx, dx        ;This is what actually reduces the task
 lea si, num
InnerLoop:
 mov al, [si]      ;Reading 2 successive array elements
 mov bl, [si+1]
 cmp al, bl        ;Comparing as UNsigned numbers
 jb  NoSwap
 mov [si], bl      ;Writing them in reverse order
 mov [si+1], al
NoSwap:
 inc si
 dec cx
 jnz InnerLoop
 dec dx
 jnz OuterLoop
```

Draft 3 (loosing all of the displacements ... for no particular reason, really):

```
 mov dx, 9         ;This is number of elements minus 1
OuterLoop:
 mov cx, dx        ;This is what actually reduces the task
 lea si, num
InnerLoop:
 mov ax, [si]      ;Reading 2 successive array elements
 cmp al, ah        ;Comparing as UNsigned numbers
 jb  NoSwap
 xchg al, ah
 mov [si], ax      ;Writing them in reverse order
NoSwap:
 inc si
 dec cx
 jnz InnerLoop
 dec dx
 jnz OuterLoop
```